# Limited options for source code path for Delta Live Tables (DLT)

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

When I run jobs, I can point to a file on Github or Azure Devops, and specify the branch I want the job to read from.

However when I create a DLT pipeline, I can point only to files on Databricks, and I cannot specify a branch. Pointing to a shared repo on a git provider would make sense... what is the recommended way to run DLT pipelines without this ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported yet. The solution would be to have a checkouts of repository on the specific branch and point DLT pipeline to it. [This demo](https://github.com/alexott/dlt-files-in-repos-demo) repository shows how to achieve this using separate checkouts for development, staging & production.